# pyspark: intersection of multiple dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark 2.0 I've this dataframe:

```
my_df = spark.createDataFrame([{'id': '0001', 'site': 'R1', 'visit': 100},
                               {'id': '0002', 'site': 'R1', 'visit': 50},
                               {'id': '0001', 'site': 'R2', 'visit': 100},
                               {'id': '0002', 'site': 'R2', 'visit': 50},
                               {'id': '0003', 'site': 'R3', 'visit': 60},
                               {'id': '0003', 'site': 'R4', 'visit': 60},
                               {'id': '0004', 'site': 'R3', 'visit': 40}])
```

describing the user `id`, the name of a visited web-`site` and how many times he/she visited that website.

Note that - for not relevant reasons - given a certain `id` its `visit` value is always the same (e.g. `id` `0001` has always `100` as `visit` value).

So for example: the id `0001` visits `100` times the `R1` site.
In particular, I have only 30 possible sites, and distinct 25k users. Up to now, to the best of my knowledge the rows of my dataframe is unpredictable, but for sure over 2 millions.

I would like to calculate for each couple of websites (in this case: `R1` vs `R2`, `R1` vs `R3`, `R1` vs `R4`, `R2` vs `R3`, `R2` vs `R4` and so on) the sum of total visits of the users they have in common.

For example:

- for the couple `R1` vs `R2` I have two users in common: `R1` has `0001` and `0002`, `R2` has `0001` and `0002`, so the intersection is `0001` and `0002` and finally the total number of visits is `100+50=150`.
- for the couple `R1` vs `R3` I have no users in common so the total number is `0`

My idea is too trivial and too slow. In fact I would:

1. iterate on all possibile couples of channel `c1` and `c2`
2. filter by `c1` and `c2`
3. intersect the `id`s of the two filtered dataframes and sum the relative `visit` number

Any idea to solve this problem better?

Comment: can you describe your data ? How many entries ? How many users ? sites ?

Comment: @eliasah 30 distinct websites, 25k distinct users and over 2millions of rows

Comment: You can then index the websites and create matrix entries. You'll be dealing with tall and skinny matrices then. But answering your question can still be quite broad.

Comment: @eliasah not sure i understand, can you explain with more details?

Comment: You have to transform your data into a matrix readable format by spark. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html

Comment: yes, i transform dataframe in matrix indexing the websites. but at the end i deal with an iteration over all sites, intersecting the ids of the 'rows' and sum the relative number of visits...isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134860/discussion-between-nicola-and-eliasah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want as output for the total visits, but converting to a table (or view) can help think in terms of SQL.

Here is my attempt. It doesn't give the 150 like in your example, but hope the approach gives you a way to solve your problem:

```
my_df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_t")

spark.sql("""
select t1.site, t2.site, sum(t1.visit + t2.visit) as totalvisits
from my_t t1 
join my_t t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t1.site < t2.site 
group by t1.site, t2.site
""").show()
```

This outputs:

```
+----+----+-----+
|site|site|total|
+----+----+-----+
|  R3|  R4|  120|
|  R1|  R2|  300|
+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: why are you not sure what exactly I want? If you explain your doubts well I give you the information you need (meanwhile see my edits).
Your attempt seems to be a good way: but why are you summing t1.visit + t2.visit? don't these values are always coincident?

Comment: My solution would be a little different from the arun one: i would sum up only t1.visit.
@eliasah what do you think about this solution in terms of correctness and performance?

Comment: I'm sorry arun but this is quite bad @Nicola. This is just a cross join and it won't scale and maybe it won't even do the job for you

Comment: Cross joining isn't any processing engine nor RDBMS's best mate. Now if you are satisfied with that @Nicola, let it be. I would never do that personally.

Comment: @eliasah why are you saying that maybe it wont even do the job for me? apart that i would sum up only t1.visit seems (PERFORMANCE apart) be the right way...

Comment: what I mean is that this might break on cross join resulting in a memory error

Comment: @Nicola Like eliasah says maybe this is not the best way to do this. Why don't you try the approach on samples of your data set and see if it scales or not? Optimization is important, but having a baseline working solution never hurts.